# Adding acid to hard water to prevent limescale deposition

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry

Acid is commonly used to remove deposited limescale. If I wanted to prevent build-up of limescale in appliances, would it make sense to add acid to the water in the first place if that doesn't harm the appliance?

As far as I understand, limescale gets produced when calcium bicarbonate turns into calcium carbonate when some of the dissolved $\ce{CO2}$ goes airborne, making the water less acidic and thereby shifting the equilibrium from bicarbonate to the less soluble carbonate.

If I now add acetic acid, according to my understanding that should keep the equilibrium on the bicarbonate side. What acid concentration do I need for different water hardnesses if this trick actually works?

I'm thinking of using it in my cleaning robot. The small valves are getting clogged very quickly. A percent of vinegar in the water shouldn't harm the tank. But prevent the clog ups.

Comment: What appliances would you be treating? Coffee maker? Hot water heater?

Comment: The amount of acid is proportional to the concentration of calcium bicarbonate. If this concentration is low, a small amount of acid will do.

Comment: @maurice Can you make it more precise? Is it equal concentration roughly? And just dependent on concentration of bicarbonate? Some actual numbers would be nice :)

Comment: One degree water hardness corresponds to around 0.3mM, so for standard hardness 10 you need 3mM acid, or 180mg acetic acid per L. At 5% weight concentration in vinegar, that's around 1mL vinegar per L of water. Does that sound right?

Comment: @ Cornelius. Your calculations seems correct.